# The word "times" for multiplication...?

Tags: math-history, philosophy

The word "times" for multiplication operation which is quite touching to the concept of time (feeling time this way 0*1=0). When was introduced that term? Did any other language have the kind of term for multiplication?

Comment: Possibly more appropriate for *History of Science and Mathematics SE*

Comment: In Swedish "one time" is translated as "en gång", and "4 times 5" is translated as "4 gånger 5". Also "how many times" is "hur många gånger".

Comment: In french the term is "fois", which appears in other expressions as well ("à la fois" - in the same time, "la première fois" - the first time etc.), but always with the same kind of meaning. This comes originally from latin and brings the meaning of "tour, succession, alternative".

Comment: In Dutch: $1\times4$ is "$1$ keer $4$" and "keer" appears "vele keren" (many times) in common language.

Comment: You seem to be overthinking it (perhaps english is not your first language?). When we say "five *times*" something, we simply mean that there are five of those things. It's got nothing to do with *time* itself. For example, you would say "I read this book five times".

Comment: I think "times" was probably introduced as a synonym for "copies of"; so $3 \times 4$ would be "$3$ copies of $4$." I doubt it has anything to do with *time* per se.

Answer (score 2):

See Anthony Lo Bello, [Origins of mathematical words :  A Comprehensive Dictionary of Latin, Greek, and Arabic Roots](https://books.google.it/books?id=LfEEAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA1) (2013), page 218 :

> *multiple* This is derived from the Latin adjective *multiplex, multiplicis*, which means folded many times. In late Latin, *multiplex* became *multiplus*, and this accounts for the absence of the c in *multiple*.

See latin [multiplico](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/multiplico)

> *Etymology* : From *multus* (“much, many”) + *plicō* (“fold, double up”).

This latin [plicō](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plico#Latin), like the ancient Greek : *πλεκτός* - "plaited, twisted", comes from Indo-European *pleḱ-* : “to plait, to weave”.

See in English : *to fold, manifold, twofold*.

---

In "current" Italian, we can say :

> "due *volte* dieci fa venti"

for : "two times ten is twenty".

An ancient vernacular manuscript of around 1300 uses :

> "doi *via* dece fa vinti";

see :

- Jens Høyrup, [Jacopo da Firenze's Tractatus Algorismi and Early Italian Abbacus Culture](https://books.google.it/books?id=XZhPC1Y-SOUC&pg=PA204) (2007), page 204.

Both italian terms (the ancient and the current one) are not strictly connected with *time*; but in "due volte dieci" the word "volta" is used also in context like "dar la volta", which means : rovesciare, i.e. *reverse*.

Thus, it share with "times" and similar the role of express a "factor of repetition" or iteration, like in : "how many times ?"

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. OP was asking about the concept of *time* as it relates to multiplication.

Comment: The Latin word “plico” does not come from the Greek: it’s a common Indo-European root.

Answer (score -1):

Google says it was introduced in late middle English.

[image]

Comment: I think I'm going to be ill ...

Comment: It says “Middle English” (like Chaucer). “Old English” means like Beowulf. They’re two very different breeds of cat.

Comment: @Lubin Indeed, people often confuse Middle English and Early Modern English for Old English, so I typically refer to OE as Anglo-Saxon instead.